# What are the other mean of connectivity apart from bluetooth?

Tags: java-me

I want to consider all the connectivity possibilities in JavaME , connectivity between phone mobile and PC. Apart from bluetooth what are the possible means of such connectivity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a look at the Generic Connection Framework (GCF) which gives you the ablility to open connections using various protocols. You do this my using a [Connector](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/Connector.html) object.

It is obviously completely dependant upon the hardware upon the phone and any optional JSRs that it implements, but you can communicate to a phone via:

- Using internet protocols e.g. Http, Datagram, Socket connections (Requires PC to be accessible via the internet)
- NFC (Near Field Communication)
- Using a Secure Element (SATSA)
- Serial COMM port connection (I think)

I'll completely admit that using some of these methods to communicate between a PC and a phone are nuts but it could be done.

The best thing to do for simplicity is to use bluetooth or a HttpConnection.

Answer (score 0):

U also able to connect mobile with pc via internet (Gprs).Better u look at the Generic Connection Framework (GCF) documentation.It will help u